# Ubuntu 22.04 stuttering

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, wayland, 22.04

Fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 with visual stuttering on both wayland and Xorg (disabled wayland on `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and rebooted). [Here is a recording](https://webmshare.com/play/1yDwe) showing the stuttering on the gnome terminal, and [here is a recording](https://webmshare.com/play/Lb1j4) showing the stuttering when moving the gnome terminal window. Please note the spike in CPU usage on the latter example.

If I go to the "text mode" with ctrl + alt + f3, there is no stuttering. Also, on Ubuntu 21.10 I had no such issue.

I have a i7 9770k and RTX 2070.

What should I do?

Comment: Please confirm you have the recommended Nvidia drivers installed and running before anything else.

Comment: Sorry. It is installed: https://pasteboard.co/ScF0TczkpOa9.png

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot in UEFI? You can do that unless dual-booting with Windows 11 in which case you need to use MOKutil to sign the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: `mokutil --sb-state` says `SecureBoot disabled`, even tough my UEFI has Secure Boot enabled. I am planning on using Windows 11, so I guess mokutil is the way to go. Is this something all nvidia owners have to do?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong don't have answers for you, but I have the same stuttering. On Ubuntu 22.04 with I9-10885H and GTX1650. Did you manage to find any improvement?

Comment: @JanneMattila no luck so far. I haven't tried the `mokutil` tool yet, though. I am back to Ubuntu 19.10 and waiting for an update from Canonical to fix this.

Comment: @JanneMattila I gave Ubuntu 22.04 a try yesterday. After updating to the latest drivers, everything is much better now. It is not flawless, but pretty usable.

Comment: @FredericoSchardong that's nice! I improved my own UI experience by toggling "Force (Full) Composition Pipeline", which removed some screen tearing that I was experiencing: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Avoid_screen_tearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue  Turned out it was the driver
In terminal

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

This told me what model my GPU is and  generated a list  the top  of that list is the preferred driver.
So I did an update and an upgrade then

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

then I installed the driver from the top of that list and rebooted

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450
```

Answer (score 0):

Had stuttering / choppy audio on mij Ubuntu 23.04. Took me a long time to discover a potential solution. I disabled the use of Waylan, rebooted and it seems to have disappeared.

My config Windows 10 with Virtualbox 7.0.8 as host. Client is Ubuntu 23.04. Everything completely patched and up-to-date. The post which brought the solution:
[How do I use X instead of wayland on 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a USB-C hub connected to my Dell XPS 15 9570, running X11 on Ubuntu 23.04. All kinds of peripherals were connected there, including my external 42 inch 4K display (LG C3). Even though the hub supported up to 4K 60Hz I regularly experienced stuttering and flickering graphics - which was really driving me crazy.

After some trial and error with both software (drivers, kernels, display settings) and hardware (using different USB-C ports, different hubs) I could find a working solution.

**Solution:** Now I'm using a dedicated USB-C to HDMI adapter (Anker) for the external display, which apparently supports even 4K 120Hz.

No flickering, no stuttering - just smooth graphics. Happy me!

[image]