# Visual Stuttering across entire system

Tags: drivers, 18.04, gnome, xorg, freeze

Recently I have had visual stuttering across my entire system (even if i am not running anything), similar to this recent unresolved post: [Ubuntu 22.04 stuttering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404531/ubuntu-22-04-stuttering) (see the recording)

Unlike them, this seems to be resolved on a reinstall for me as a live USB of Ubuntu did not have this issue, however I would really like to avoid reinstalling.

As they said this does not occur with crtl + alt + f3 and there is a spike in cpu usage. Audio seems to be unaffected, and also seems to occur with both the nvidia and xorg drivers.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and have a GTX 1060 and a Ryzen 5 2600.

Answer (score -1):

Just reporting i had the same; or similar; issue.

the visual stuttering took the form of mouse skipping when in the desktop environment but upon using ctrl + alt + f3 inside the commandline interface the screen would flicker.

I used nano to create a blank file at `/etc/x11/xorg.conf` where one did not exist previously and rebooted my machine, the hitching went away.

**Steps:**

1. ctrl + alt + f3
2. login as a user with root access
3. sudo nano /etc/x11/xorg.conf
4. save
5. power cycle machine